# XAMPP + OS X + shell_exec = Keychain

Tags: apache2, keychain

i try to execute an shell command, for example:
I have installed cupertino (https://github.com/nomad/cupertino/) to have access on my device-lists:

```
 <?php
      var_dump(shell_exec("ios login < user.aid 2>&1"));
 ?>
```

The **user.aid** is an text file with the Apple credentials (`File extension: .aid = Apple I D`) with following contents:

```
 my-appleid@domain.tld[\n]
 thePasswordFromTheAppleID1337[\n]
 [\n]
```

My idea was to add these to my private development system for online building/compiling.
My Mac mini is on my company and on my root server i have installed `TeamCity`.

The problem is: When i try to use shell commands, i must enter the username and password after the system says "keychain not found".

How i can set a special keychain for Apache in XAMPP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
Change the username in httpd.conf